# Remove node from pos (i)

Tags: java

So I'm trying to create a linkedlist for school and I've discussed with my teacher and understand that the previous node from the node you initially want to remove shall "replace" the node you want to remove, but I can't really figure out why my code isn't working. and yes I know that my code for removing the "head" isn't complete.

```
public class linkedList<T> {

    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;

    private int size;


    public linkedList() {
            head = tail = null;
            size = 0;
    }

    public T remove(int pos){
        Node<T> temp = head;
        Node<T> removeNode = null;


        if(pos >= size)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("That posistion doesn't excist.");

        for(int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++) {
            temp = temp.next;  

            if(pos == 0) {
                head = temp.next;
                head = null;
            } else if(i < pos - 1) {
                temp.next = null;
                removeNode = temp.next;
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }

        removeNode = temp;

        size--;
        return removeNode.getElement();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and note that "why my code isn't working" isn't helpful. We need more information, e.g. what input do you have and what do you get?

Comment: What is your question? Can you please clarify what you mean by 'I can't really figure out why my code isn't working'? If *that* is your question, you need to be crystal clear about what is not working, give us the stack traces and 'what should happen' versus 'what does happen'

Comment: `else if(i < pos - 1) ...`  you probably don't want to execute that block for every node that is before the one you want to remove. Also `temp.next = null; removeNode = temp.next;` will effectively be equivalent to `temp.next = null; removeNode = null;`.

Comment: Basically you want to iterate (run the loop) until you hit the node at the position you want to remove. _Then_ you remove it, e.g. by calling `node.prev.next = node.next;` for all nodes but the `head` and `node.next.prev = node.prev;` for all but `tail`.

Comment: okay so what I meant was, I'm having problem removing the node from pos 1 and making the node from pos 0 replace the node from pos 1, however I fixed the code for removing pos 0. Hopefully this helps you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp.next = null;
removeNode = temp.next;
temp = temp.next;
```

This just sets everything to null, and it's executed every iteration of the foreach loop. This should be changed to something that doesn't just clear everything, and it should only be executed once.

Once you find the correct Node, the 'next' variable of the previous one should be updated, and the 'previous' reference of the next Node.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your else branch:

You set `temp.next` to `null`. Then you set `removeNode` to `temp.next` - what you previously set to `null`.

I recommend you draw a little sketch with the objects and the links between it. Then you see that your solution must be something like `temp.next.next`...